# Conditionally Hiding / Stopping a view from display

Tags: views

I have two views, for taxonomy pages, one displays the products of the current term (using contextual filter "Content:has taxonomy term"), and other display the sub-categories of the term (using contextual filter "Taxonomy term: Parent term").

My problem is that I want to display product view only when I does not get any result in sub-category view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a block, then create a tpl.php file for the block and inside it put

```
<?php

$view = views_get_view('view_name_of_subcategory');
$view->set_display('block_1');
$view->execute();
        // results are now stored as an array in $view->result
$count = count( $view->result );

if ($count = 0) { print views_embed_view('view_name_of_products','block_2' } 
else { print $view->render(); }

?>
```

Replace block_1 & block_2 with your actual machine name, you can find it here (see picture)

[image]

**PS** if `($count = 0)` does  not work try if `($count = null)`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion of using block.

It gave me an idea to make block of my product list view, and then I displayed it only on required URLs(catalog/*).

And then in block's PHP I added following code:
        <?php
          $v = views_get_view_result('uc_catalog_terms', 'default', arg(1));
          $result = count($v);
          if ($result == 0) {
           return TRUE;
          }
          else {
           return FALSE;
                        }
        ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "NO RESULTS BEHAVIOR" from views (on the right side) and choose "Global: View area" to select your view you want to display if there aren't any results.